# Woher kommt »auseinanderklamüsern«?

Tags: verb, etymology

In meiner Familie (insbesondere jenem Teil, der nicht aus dem Gebiet ist, das mein Avatar nahelegt) wird öfters davon gesprochen, dass etwas *auseinanderklamüsert* werden müsste. Zum Beispiel:

> Oh Gott, was ein Kabelsalat. Willst du den auseinanderklamüsern? (= entwirren)
>
> Ich muss die farbigen Kügelchen auseinanderklamüsern (= nach Farben sortieren)
>
> Versuch die Staubfänger mal auseinanderzuklamüsern, dass keiner mehr einen anderen berührt. Pass auf: Die ziehen sich gegenseitig magisch an. (= trennen)

Die Bedeutung ergibt sich aus diesen Beispielen: etwas voneinander trennen, entwirren, nach Arten sortieren, wobei eine gewisse Fieselarbeit vonnöten ist – die CD-Sammlung nach Interpreten zu sortieren würde nicht als *auseinanderklamüsern* durchgehen.

---

Mich interessiert aber nicht die Bedeutung sondern die Herkunft, zumal ich das Verb auf keine mir bekannte Wurzel zurückführen kann. Woher stammt der Ausdruck? Auf welche Wortwurzeln lässt er sich zurückführen?

---

Bonusfrage (da in meiner näheren bairischen Umgebung niemand sonst das Wort benutzt): In welchen Gebieten Deutschlands wird es verwendet? Dafür existiert [diese Wiki-Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/33935); bitte regionale Verbreitung in diese einfügen.

Comment: Ich kenne das Wort zwar, verwende es aber nicht und kenne auch niemanden, der es verwenden würde (Osten Österreichs). Hierzulande wird »auseinanderklauben« verwendet, wo in deinen Beispielen » auseinanderklamüsern« verwendet wird. Das Verb »klauben« hat aber die Bedeutung »aufheben, aufsammeln«. (Erdäpfel klauben = Kartoffel ernten, Äpfel/Birnen klauben = Fallobst vom Boden aufsammeln. Äpfel vom Baum pflücken wäre »Äpfel brocken«.)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Und in meinem Teil Bayerns taucht *klauben* in der Regel als *auf-* oder *zusammenklauben* auf. Fürs *Trennen* würde ichs eher nicht verwenden.

Comment: Ich kenne *zusammenklauben* als Synonym für *klauben* und als Synonym für *einsammeln* (»Klaubt eure Sachen zusammen, wir brechen auf.«)

Answer (score 10):

Der Ausdruck ist norddeutsch. Er ist abgeleitet von den Kalmäusern. Daraus resultiert zuerst das Verb *klamüsern* (=*grübeln*) und davon abgeleitet sind *ausklamüsern* (=*durch Probieren herausfinden*) und eben *auseinanderklamüsern*.

Während laut Duden die Herkunft von *Kalmäuser* ungeklärt ist, ist [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/klam%C3%BCsern) dort schon etwas detaillierter.

> klamüsern Vb. ‘grübeln, in der Stube hocken’, älter kalmäusern (16. Jh.). Zugrunde liegt Kalmüser, Klamüser ‘Sinnierer, Grübler, spitzfindiger Geselle’, das noch heute im Nd. gebräuchlich und seit dem 16. Jh. (auch obd.) in vielen Bedeutungsnuancen belegt ist (‘Schmarotzer, Geizhals, armer Schlucker, Knauser, Schulmeister, weltfremder Stubengelehrter’). Man kann ausgehen von rotw. Kammesierer ‘gelehrter Bettler’, zu jidd. komaz ‘nehmen (mit voller Hand)’, kamzon ‘Geizhals’, das wohl von lat. calamus ‘Rohr, Schreibrohr, Feder’ beeinflußt wird, so daß Kalmäuser, Klamäuser, Kalmüser oder Klamüser als der ‘unfruchtbare Gelehrte’ zu verstehen ist. Das Verb ist vom Substantiv abgeleitet, vgl. noch heute nd. kalmüsern, klamüsern ‘grübeln, umhersuchen’, nhd. ausklamüsern ‘austüfteln’ (19. Jh.).

Noch ausführlicher wird es im [Grimmschen Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GK00709#XGK00709).

Answer (score 3):

### Gegenden, in denen *auseinanderklamüsern* in dieser Bedeutung bekannt ist und verwendet wird:

- südliches Niedersachsen, Hannover, Braunschweig
- nördliches Niedersachsen (*klamüsern* kommt außerdem im Plattdeutsch vor)
- nördliches Sachsen-Anhalt
- Köln, Düsseldorf, Aachen und Umgebung (Niederrhein, Bergisches Land, Nordeifel)
- Berlin

### Gegenden, in denen der Ausdruck *nicht* benutzt wird:

- südwestliches Oberbayern.
- östliches Österreich.

(ob er verstanden wird ist nebensächlich)

Comment: Ich kenne und verwende es auch. Region Stuttgart. Könnte allerdings Einfluss von Verwandtschaft im Saarland sein.

Comment: @Iris An sich ist *klamüsern* im Süden mMn nicht heimisch. Ich kenne es auch, verwende es aber sehr selten.